# Можно ли файлы DBF, созданные Visual FoxPro 7 или 9, открыть в Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, dbf

Перед обновлением до *Excel 2010*, я мог открывать DBF-файлы, созданные в *Visual FoxPro 7* или *9* в *Excel 2003*.

Я не уверен, но кажется, почему-то именно после установки *Excel 2010* я больше не могу открыть файл.

Я получил сообщение об ошибке, когда попытался открыть файл DBF в *Excel 2010*:

> файл, который вы пытаетесь открыть в другом формате, чем файл с указанным расширением

Я попытался открыть файл DBF через *File->Open*, но он все еще не может работать.

Если я копирую файл к более низкому формату DBF (тип *fox2x*) тогда я в состоянии открыть файл в *Excel 2010*.

Можно ли файлы DBF, созданные *Visual FoxPro 7* или *9*, открыть в *Excel 2010*?

Comment: сталкивался с тем же самым, для себя нашел следующее решение: средствами `foxpro` сохранял необходимые мне данные в csv(там помоему есть и другие форматы). пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2281093/5610621)